# WSL - webcam USB : Can not open camera by index

Tags: python, opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, uvc

I have followed this tutorial: https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win/wiki/WSL-support#usbip-client-tools

I successfully connect my USB camera with my WSL2, but can not open the camera.

```
$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:08cb Logitech, Inc. Mic (Notebooks Pro)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My camera USB is **Logitech, Inc. Mic (Notebooks Pro)** and my program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it shows

```
[ WARN:0@0.009] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
```

I’ve used v4l-utils to query my container’s video devices

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

I have added some config in Device Driver like @NotTheDr01ds said and now my camera show up in WSL2 with command

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
UVC Camera (046d:08c9) (usb-vhci_hcd.0-1):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
```

But when I tried to run my program, its showed

```
[ WARN:0@10.310] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1000) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.
```

The light of camera is on but can not capture anything. I have tried these command below:

```
lsmod
rmmod uvcvideo
modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000
```

but its showed error

```
rmmod uvcvideo
rmmod: ERROR: Module uvcvideo is builtin.
```

I have not find any solutions yet. Any suggestion??

Comment: Mine is working . I used picamera

Comment: I can connect my webcam USB to wsl2, but can not open the webcam

Comment: Are you using raspberry pi?

Comment: No, I'm not bro, I'm using Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide a complete answer at this point, but here's what I know so far about camera support under WSL2:

- You have the first step correct by sharing the camera via USB/IP, but that's unfortunately only part of the process.
- WSL2's kernel does not include any media drivers by default either, so you'll definitely need to add those to your kernel:

  ```
  sudo apt install build-essential flex bison dwarves libssl-dev libelf-dev 
  libncurses-dev
  mkdir ~/src
  cd ~/src
  git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linu
  x-Kernel.git
  make KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl menuconfig
  ```

  Enable the following options. All should be enabled as built-in, not modules. The option should have an "*" next to it rather than an "M":

  - Select Device Drivers -> Enable Multimedia support
  - Select Multimedia support -> Media Drivers: Enable Media USB Adapters
  - Select Media USB Adapters: Enable USB Video Class (UVC)
  - Save the config to "Microsoft/config-wsl.uvc" (or whatever you want to call it)
  - Exit menuconfig

  ```
  make KCONFIG_CONFIG=Microsoft/config-wsl.uvc
  ```

  - (A bit fuzzy on the details here since it's been a few weeks since I did it) Copy the platform `bzImage` to a location on your Windows drive.
  - Update the `.wslconfig` file in your *Windows* user profile directory to point to the new kernel (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig) for starters).
  - `wsl --shutdown` and restart to load the new kernel
  - Confirm it is in play with `uname -a`
  - Still working on this part, but it seems to help if you disable the device driver for the camera in Windows.  Otherwise Linux and Windows will be fighting for control.

Even with all that in place, I have not been able to capture video yet.  I can at least get the camera to show up in WSL2 after that as evidenced with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.

Hope that helps you at least make some progress.  I'd be interested in knowing if you solve it completely.

Comment: I have gone through again my configration and add some more config as you said about Device Drivers option and now it is showed up with command v4l2-ctl --list-devices. When I tried to run program, the webcam light is on, that's mean it's activating but the line ret, frame = cap.read() can not capture anything